# Stored procedure returns an array; how to use in SQL?

Tags: sql, h2

I am writing an accounting system backed by an h2 database.  The tree of accounts is stored in the ACCOUNTS table, with the PARENT_ID column storing the links in the tree.

To get the path to a given node in the tree, I have the following stored procedure:

`public static Object[] getAncestorPKs(Long id)`

whose job is to produce an array of integers, being the PARENT_ID values between the given node and the root of the tree.  I register the procedure in the database under the name ANCESTOR_PKS like this:

`CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS ANCESTOR_PKS FOR "xxx.yyy.zzz.getAncestorPKs"`

My problem is I can't seem to find a way to use the thing without triggering a SQLException!  I need to use it in the following way:

`SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE [...] AND ID IN ANCESTOR_PKS(5) [for example]`

I get the following error:

`Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN ANCESTOR_PKS[*](5) "; expected "("`

But there *is* a bracket after ANCESTOR_PKS!!!  What on earth is going on here?  Is there some way to use IN with the result of a stored procedure?  I have searched and searched, but all the examples of the use of IN that I see are with literal arrays, and no-one seems to think of showing how to *use* an array which is the return value of a stored procedure.

Help???

Comment: what does `SELECT ANCESTOR_PKS(5)` return? (Or something that just selects the stored procedure)

Comment: It returns a result set with one row, which contains an object of type `org.h2.value.ValueArray` containing (x, y, z) where x, y, z are the nodes in the path between node 5 and the root, i.e. exactly the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with h2, but [this page](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#condition_right_hand_side) says you must place () around the array.

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN (ANCESTOR_PKS(5))
```

Maybe you even have to add a subselect

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN (SELECT ANCESTOR_PKS(5))
```

Comment: Wow, I'm sure I've already tried that, but I guess not, because when I try it today I no longer get the error...however, I get another one!  Now I get `Data conversion error converting "(x, y, z)"`  Can someone point me in the right direction to resolve _this_ problem?  Many thanks for getting me past the original problem...I really was starting to tear my hair out!

Comment: BTW: my Java method has to be declared as returning Object[] (see [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions), section Function Data Type Mapping), but the return value actually contains Longs.

Comment: @user1547739 Hmm... Is this the whole error message? I think you should close this question (click on the hook left of the answer) and start a new one, because no one (except myself) will still read this comments here to answer it.