# h2: "data conversion error" on array returned from stored procedure

Tags: arrays, stored-procedures, h2

This is a followup post to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658251/stored-procedure-returns-an-array-how-to-use-in-sql#comment15451220_11658251).  I am writing an accounting system backed by an h2 database. The tree of accounts is stored in the ACCOUNTS table, with the PARENT_ID column storing the links in the tree.

To get the path to a given node in the tree, I have the following stored procedure:

```
public static Long[] getAncestorPKs(Long id)
```

whose job is to produce an array of integers, being the PARENT_ID values between the given node and the root of the tree.  Let's imagine it is defined like this (because I have tried this and I get the same error):

```
public static Long[] getAncestorPKs(Long id)
{
  return new Long[]{new Long(1), new Long(2), new Long(3)};
}
```

It is properly registered in the database and I can call it from within a SQL query.  My problem is that h2 seems to be unable to deal with the return value: if I use it like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN (ANCESTOR_PKS(5))
```

then I get the following error:

```
Data conversion error converting "(1, 2, 3)"; SQL statement:
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN (ANCESTOR_PKS(5)) [22018-167]
```

If, instead, I send the following to the database:

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

I get back a result set with 3 rows, containing the three integers (exactly what I expect).

I really can't see what is the problem here!  I am returning an array of Longs, which are to be used in comparing against a column which contains BIGINTS.  Why is h2 refusing to convert this array?  I have tried making the return value be Object[], because the h2 documentation is not entirely clear whether this is required on the return side as well as on the call side, but that makes no difference at all.  I'm just banging my head against a brick wall here.  This ain't rocket science!  Surely someone has written similar code before?

Many thanks in advance, before I go mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method returns an array of objects, then for the database this is one value of data type [ARRAY](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type). And not a table with 3 rows. But of course you don't use the data type ARRAY in your table, you use INT or BIGINT. So your query is incorrect.

Either the method needs to return a ResultSet, or you need to convert the array value to a table. To do that, you could use the function [`TABLE(..)`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#table) as follows:

```
select x from table(x bigint = getAncestorPKs(1));
```

So what you could do is:

```
drop table accounts;
create table accounts(id int);
insert into accounts values(1), (2), (10), (20);
drop alias getAncestorPKs;
create alias getAncestorPKs as 'Long[] getAncestorPKs(Long id) {
  return new Long[]{new Long(1), new Long(2), new Long(3)};
}';
select * from accounts where id in
(select x from table(x bigint = getAncestorPKs(1)));
```

Comment: Thanks hugely Thomas, this indeed solves the problem.  But I would like to understand why I can use an array literal in a query, but _not_ an array which is returned by a stored procedure.

Comment: The expression `column IN(x, y,...)` is not actually an array literal; it is a list of simple values. I can understand why this is confusing. It is a bit similar to `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(x, y,...)`: here, the values list isn't an array either. It's also a list of simple values.

Comment: Ah OK, many thanks again :)  So, I guess the `select x from table(...)` expression also creates a list of values, not a result set?

Comment: The `in(select ...)` doesn't either internally create a result set nor a list of values. But the problem was that your method returns an array value.